# Python 3 - How to create a typing effect in command line window

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, command-prompt

So I am having a slight problem.
I have this code:

```
def typingeffect(string):
    string = list(string)
    for i in string:
        print(i, end="")
        sleep(0.2)

typingeffect("Hello")
```

When I run this code through Python's (3.7) IDLE, it works as expected, putting one character after another with a delay of 0.2 seconds. However, when I run it through cmd.exe, it just prints it as one string.

It only works through command if I take out `end=""`, in which case, it prints the letters with a delay on 0.2 seconds, but with a newline after each character resulting not in a typing effect, but with:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

If anybody has a solution to why this is happening and how it can be fixed, I would be very grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `flush` parameter for `print` to always flush the output buffer after each call:

```
def typingeffect(string):
    for i in string:
        print(i, end="", flush=True)
        sleep(0.2)
```

Otherwise flushes for standard output typically only occur for newlines.